# Clarification on SQL Syntax

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

Clarification on my SQL Syntax

Does the `WHERE` condition look for `INSURANCECODE` only with `CASH` or `''`
and `PLANNAME = NULL` ?

```
select * 
from report rpt
left join InsurancePlan Ip on IP.PlanName  = rpt.PrimaryPlanName
where
   (rpt.InsuranceCode in ('CASH', '') or Ip.PlanName is null)
```

Comment: Unsure what you're asking here. Can you clarify, explain more?

Answer (score 3):

The `OR` takes priority, meaning you will effectively get any row that has *either* or *both* of the two conditions, ie.

1. If `rpt.InsuranceCode` has the value `CASH` or an empty string
2. If `Ip.PlanName` is null

if *either*, or *both* conditions are met, you will get a row in your resultset.

You could think of the query as the following as well:

```
WHERE
    rpt.InsuranceCode = 'CASH'
 OR rpt.InsuranceCode = ''
 OR Ip.PlanName IS NULL
```

In the following example table, the rows that would end up in the resultset is marked with a * to the right:

```
InsuranceCode    PlanName    ResultSet    Why?
'CASH'           'Whatever'      *        rpt.InsuranceCode = 'CASH'
''               'Whatever'      *        rpt.InsuranceCode = ''
'Whatever'       NULL            *        Ip.PlanName IS NULL
'CASH'           NULL            *        Both
''               NULL            *        Both
'Whatever'       'Whatever'               Neither
```

Answer (score 0):

Basically your query will return rows that have an InsuranceCode equal to 'CASH' or '', as well as rows that have a NULL value for PlanName

Answer (score -1):

The way you have it now you will get insuranceCode = cash AND insuranceCode = ''  OR the planName is null. So all planeName = null will show regardless of insCode and planName will have values for codes that are '' or cash. 
If you want all rows to have a null planName change the OR to AND

Comment: That answer doesn't do much in clarifying anything. For starters, there's no way InsuranceCode can be both cash and an empty string, so the "AND" in there is misplaced.